# Prove $\mathbb Q (\sqrt2 + \sqrt3 ) = \mathbb Q (\sqrt2 , \sqrt3 )$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

So correct if I am wrong, but these sets are:

$\mathbb Q (\sqrt2 + \sqrt3 )=\{a+b\sqrt2 + c\sqrt3 +d \sqrt6 : a,b,c,d \in \mathbb Q \}$

$\mathbb Q (\sqrt2 , \sqrt3 )=\{a+b\sqrt2 + c\sqrt3  : a,b,c \in \mathbb Q \}$

Was trying to see if the LHS is a subset of RHS and vise versa.

Let $A \in \mathbb Q (\sqrt2 , \sqrt3 )$ with $A=a+b\sqrt2 + c\sqrt3= a+b\sqrt2 + c\sqrt3  + d \sqrt6 - d \sqrt6 = a+b\sqrt2 + c\sqrt3  + d \sqrt6 - d \sqrt3 \sqrt2 $ but i can't really do anything after this. If you factor the root $3$ or $2$, it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: A field that contains $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ contains its reciprocal. Compute the reciprocal.

Comment: @AndréNicolas why isnt the reciprecol $(a+ b\sqrt2 + c\sqrt3 + d\sqrt6 )^{-1}$? dont u take the general form of each element in the set?

Comment: It suffices to show that $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ are in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$. (The other direction is trivial.). If $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is in the field, its reciprocal $\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}$ is in, therefore the sum $2\sqrt{3}$ is in, therefore $\sqrt{3}$ is in.  Note this is the same idea as a couple of the answers, except I am using division instead of squaring and manipulating.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I cant see how the other direction is trivial. Can you show me how that works please!

Comment: If $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ are in a certain field, their sum is in the field.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I feel like this question has nothing to do with looking how the elements in the two sets actually look like in general terms. Let me get this straight: If we have $$\mathbb Q (\sqrt2, \sqrt3 )$$ then $\sqrt2 , \sqrt3 \in \mathbb Q (\sqrt2, \sqrt3 )$ which means that their sum which is $$\sqrt2 + \sqrt3 \in \mathbb Q (\sqrt2 + \sqrt3)$$ ??? Because of the operations within a field.

Comment: We are proving that each of the fields is a subfield of the other. The easier part is to show that $Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$ is a subfield of $Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}$. For clearly $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ are in the field on the right, so their sum is, so all of $Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$ is.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So for the hard part, in words, can you explain what we are doing please. Are we taking an inverse element of $\mathbb Q (\sqrt2 + \sqrt3)$ and then manipulating it so that it is in $\mathbb Q (\sqrt2 , \sqrt3)$?

Comment: Also why are we allowed to take the inverse?

Comment: No, we are showing that both $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ are elements of $Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$, which implies all the elements of $Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ are in $Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: Why are we allowed to take the inverse? $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is in the **field** $Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$, so its inverse is.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Can I ask, what are the basis of each of the two sets? Are we meant to just show if the basis of each set exists within the other set then they are equal?

Comment: Let $H$ and $K$ be fields, with $H$ a subfield of $K$. Let $\alpha\in K$. By definition $H(\alpha)$ is the intersection of all subfields of $K$ that contain $H$ and $\alpha$. Similar for $H(\alpha,\beta)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas In exactly the same types of words you just used, can you define what $H(\alpha + \beta )$ is please.

Comment: The intersection of all subfields of $K$ that contain $H$ and $\alpha+\beta$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So in general, when showing two extended fields are equal, say $X[._x] = Y[._y]$, we show that the $._x$ is in the $Y[._y]$ and the $._y$ is in the $X[._x]$??? Sorry for the bad notation.

Comment: Probably! I cannot read what you wrote. But depending on the detailed situation, one may use some other strategy. By the way, the procedure you started, if carried out correctly, would have worked too. But it gets messy.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I see. And thanks for letting me know that my way would have worked too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will suffice to show $\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3} \in \mathbb{Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})}$ and that $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$. The latter is obvious the former is a bit trickier.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $\sqrt2+\sqrt3\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$ so by minimality $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$. For the reverse inclusion consider $(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)^2$ for example and so on.

Comment: just wondering, what do you mean by, so by minimality

Answer (score 1):

I myself had this problem a while ago, but this is because I didn't quite get the definitions. Instead of trying to explicitly describe these sets, remember the definitions.

First we take an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$, say $\mathbb{C}$. Then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ containing $\mathbb{Q}$, $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$. Similarly, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},+\sqrt{3})$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$. Well, since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is a field and contains $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$, the sum $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is in there and so $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$. To show reverse inclusion, it suffices to show that $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ are in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$ (why?). Now, $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is in there, so its square $5+2\sqrt{6}$ is in there, so its square $-5$= $2\sqrt{6}$ is in there. Then $2\sqrt{6}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})=2(2\sqrt{3}+3\sqrt{2})$ is in there. Subtracting $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ from this a few times and scaling you get what you want. Play around and have fun!

**EDIT**: André Nicolas gave a way simpler argument for showing the "hard part" in the comments. Anyways, it is always good to play around and discover things for yourself